# How to parse exclude "alt=\ when parsing text from a string?

Tags: c#, substring, indexof

example of the string:  alt="hello world" >"
i want to get only the hello world using indexof and substring.

```
int indexDescription = line.IndexOf("alt=");
int indexDescriptionEnd = line.IndexOf("\" >");
string descriptionResult = line.Substring(indexDescription, indexDescriptionEnd - indexDescription);
```

the result is:  "alt="hello world"

I can't figure out how to rid of the "alt=
I tried:

```
string descriptionResult = line.Substring(indexDescription + 6, indexDescriptionEnd - indexDescription);
```

but his give exception error:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length'

Comment: so you want only "Hello World"

Comment: @nbk right.  i have many strings like that and i want to get only the text.

Comment: How about `string descriptionResult = line.Substring(indexDescription + 6, indexDescriptionEnd - indexDescription - 6);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0) will return the index of the first occurrence of the passed string. If passed string has more than 1 character, the index is the position of the first character of that string. For your example with the string "alt=", first occurrence is at the beginning of the string, so the index is 0. You need to add the length of `"alt=\""` to your `indexDescription`. Something like:

```
int indexDescription = line.IndexOf("alt=\"") + "alt=\"".Length;
int indexDescriptionEnd = line.IndexOf("\" >");

string descriptionResult = line.Substring(indexDescription, indexDescriptionEnd - indexDescription)
```

Keep in mind though that this problem is very trivial and it'll only work for the assumptions you provided (i.e. all strings are exactly as you described them to be)